# How to style a UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout header to be separated from its children list .insetGrouped layout?

Tags: ios, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, sidebar, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm trying to mimic the appearance we find in the Mail app where the group header for mailboxes is collapsible and its children list is styled with the `.insetGrouped` layoutOption.

I tried to use `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .sidebarPlain)` as the configuration but I didn't find a way to style the .insetGrouped appearance for the sections

### Mail App:

[image: Mail app sidebar appearance]

### The closest I got to this layout was this:

[image: My app sidebar appearance]

I'm using the approach below to configure the collectionView inside my ViewController.

```swift
let mixedListLayout = 
    UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { section, env -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
    
    let listConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)

    return NSCollectionLayoutSection.list(using: listConfig, layoutEnvironment: env)
}

collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: mixedListLayout)
collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]       
collectionView.delegate = self

view.addSubview(collectionView)
```

For the cell registration my approach is something like this:

```swift
let headerRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, SidebarItem> { (cell, _, item) in

    var contentConfiguration = UIListContentConfiguration.sidebarHeader()
    contentConfiguration.text = item.title
    cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfiguration
    let outlineDisclosureConfig = UICellAccessory.OutlineDisclosureOptions(style: .header)
    cell.accessories = [.outlineDisclosure(displayed: .always, options: outlineDisclosureConfig)]
}

let primaryRowRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, SidebarItem> { (cell, _, item) in

    var contentConfiguration = UIListContentConfiguration.sidebarCell()
    contentConfiguration.text = item.title
    contentConfiguration.image = item.image

    cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfiguration
    cell.indentationLevel = 0
    if let acessoryLabel = item.subtitle {
        cell.accessories = [.label(text: acessoryLabel)]
    }
    cell.accessories.append(.disclosureIndicator())
}

dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<SidebarSection, SidebarItem>(collectionView: collectionView) {
    (collectionView, indexPath, item) -> UICollectionViewCell in

    switch item.type {
    case .header:
        return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: headerRegistration, for: indexPath, item: item)
    case .primaryRow:
        return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: primaryRowRegistration, for: indexPath, item: item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more readings on documentation I've solved it by setting the `headerMode` to `.firstItemInSection` in the `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration` so my mixedListLayout looks like this:

```swift
let mixedListLayout = 
    UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { section, env -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
    
    var listConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
    
    listConfig.headerMode = section == 0 ? .none : .firstItemInSection // Using "first

    return NSCollectionLayoutSection.list(using: listConfig, layoutEnvironment: env)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { section, env -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            self.layoutConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
            self.layoutConfig.headerMode = .firstItemInSection
            self.layoutConfig.backgroundColor = .clear

            return NSCollectionLayoutSection.list(using: self.layoutConfig, layoutEnvironment: env)
        }

let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<Cell, Item> {
            (cell, indexPath, item) in
            
            cell.item = item
            var backgroundConfig = UIBackgroundConfiguration.listGroupedHeaderFooter()
            backgroundConfig.backgroundColor = .lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
            cell.backgroundConfiguration = backgroundConfig
        }
```

[image: result]

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use [outline group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/outlinegroup) in combination with  [disclosure group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup)

[image: same][image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately I'm not using swiftUI on this component and having an UIHostingController will add unecessary complexity to the layout